# How manually update a flow without copying the entire data structure?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a structure that act as a database in my app, this is basically a tree:

```kotlin
sealed class Node {

    Note(val name: String)

    Folder(val name: String, val content: MutableList<Node>)
    
}
```

This is how i currently create my flow:

```kotlin
private val _data = MutableStateFlow(Node.Folder("", mutableListOf()))
val data: Flow<NoteFolder> = _data
```

I can sucefully emit the fist value with `_data.emit(rootFolder)`, but i'm having truble to update a nested `Node`.

I would like a function like this:

```kotlin
fun updateNestedNodeName(previousName: String, newName: String) {

    _data.update { data ->
        val note: Node.Note = data.findByName(previousName)
        note.name = newName
        data
    }
}
```

But this won't update the UI (I think this is because i'm not changing the pointer of _data so Kotlin thinks the flow hasn't change).

I feel like i'm missing something here, I've never seen anyone have this problem on the internet. Is it good design to use flows here?

Also, I would really like to avoid having to use room.

Thanks

Comment: Never mix mutable classes with StateFlow, or it will be completely broken. Use read-only List in your class and create a new copy of it when you need to change the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this because by the time you call data as return, it will return the original value of the data. Either you create a new variable for data model then modify it or copy the entire data model then change some variable in it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Should i copy the entire struct and keep flow, or should i put mutable state everywhere? (In term of performance)

Comment: i don't really recommend exposing lot of mutable state, what i do recommend is have a private ```MutableStateFlow``` inside a ```viewModel``` and exposed it as single stateflow to be observed by UI

Comment: if you want to change specific properties in the model, then yes, copy the entire structure, then modify it there. U can always create new instance of it manually but it will be a pain when your state grow bigger and bigger. I only recommend this when you're trying to reset your state in example

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture

You can refer to this article about why it's recommended to use mutablestateflow or mutablestate inside a ```ViewModel``` and just exposed the non mutable form of it.